# Wrong Co-ordinate mapping on QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using PYQT5 frame work for developing an application that will help to
annotate video, the video is being displayed in the QGraphicsScene Widget.

```
self.w = 742
self.h = 529
# Below code is responsible for displaying the scene & rectangle
self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self.graphicsView_CameraFeed)
self.scene.drawBackground = self.drawBackground
self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.setScene(self.scene)
self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, self.w, self.h)
```

The video is being drawn on the widget using the Qpainter class which is being drawn on the scene continuously at the origin, the following was the output.

[image: Video]

Using the above configurations when I was drawing the rectangles at [0,0] position the output was something which is not expected as rectangles has to be drawn on the top left since co-ordinates [0,0] are given.

[image: Rectangle with Incorrect position]

But when I changed the sceneRectangle's Origin to the following

> self.scene.setSceneRect(70,0,self.w,self.h)

I got the expected result i.e. [image: Rectangle plotted correctly]

I don't know how it worked out, but due to changing of this value there are some other issues in my application.

Here is the sample code I'm using, please don't look for syntactical errors, I've added a part of my working code only.

```
def setupUi(self):
    self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
    self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName('gridLayout_2')

    self.graphicsView_CameraFeed = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.tab)
    sizePolicy = \
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                              QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(203, 235, 255);'
            )
    self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.setObjectName('graphicsView_CameraFeed'
            )
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.graphicsView_CameraFeed, 1, 0,
                                1, 11)

def initUi(self):

        # Below code is responsible for displaying the scene & rectangle

    self.scene = \
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self.graphicsView_CameraFeed)
    self.scene.drawBackground = self.drawBackground
    self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.setScene(self.scene)
    self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, self.w, self.h)

def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
    height = self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.size().height()
    width = self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.size().width()
    self.imageScaled = self.image.scaled(width, height,
            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding)

    painter.drawImage(rect.x(), rect.y(), self.imageScaled)
    self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.fitInView(self.scene.sceneRect(),
            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

def buttonClick(self):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    w = 80
    h = 200
    box = QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, w, h)
    self.scene.addItem(box)
```

Comment: How are you drawing the rectangle? How is painted the background? Please, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Mmmh, I don't understand. You want to set fixed coordinates for the rectangle, but then you're using `fitInView()` with a fixed aspect ratio (and you also do that within the `drawBackground()`, which is a **really bad idea**). Then you set fixed absolute coordinates for the rectangle, but those coordinates won't be correctly adapted to the background, because you're constantly resizing it. How should the resizing behave? Should the scene occupy the most part of the view? Should the rectangle coordinates be relative to the image? What is the relation between the rectanglesù and the background?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are adding your rect from the buttonClick function, I don't know how you are calling that function but I'm going to assume you didn't connect it to the QGraphicsView. So theres not always a overlap between the QGraphicsView and the QGraphicsScene, So you will need to map the view coordinates to scene coordinates:

```
def buttonClick(self):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    w = 80
    h = 200
    scene_point = self.graphicsView_CameraFeed.mapToScene(x, y)
    box = QGraphicsRectItem(scene_point.x(), scene_point.y(), w, h)
    self.scene.addItem(box)
```

Comment: This won't help, as the problem is due to the scaling used for the background which doesn't account for the actual visible coordinates shown in the viewport, since those will constantly change every time the view is resized.

Comment: So he will just need to update his rect item each time the scene is changed to keep it absolute

Comment: That's a possibility, but the reality is that continuously updating the rect item is a terrible workaround in this case, since actual problem is that the whole implementation of the OP has coordinate issues, as pointed out in the comments to the question. The rectangle can (and should) keep its coordinates, what should be fixed instead is how the image is rendered and the sceneRect is set according to the transformations and the visible area in the viewport.